# how to delete subfolders without deleting parent folder and child folder?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

For this type of directory structure:

> ```
> \\rdwlhsdevserver\root\user1\folders\testdat.txt
> \\rdwlhsdevserver\root\abhay\testdat.txt
> \\rdwlhsdevserver\root\testuser\folders1\folder2\testdat.txt
> \\rdwlhsdevserver\root\devadmin\input\testdat.txt
> \\rdwlhsdevserver\root\admin\testdata\testdat.txt
> ```

I know that I can use `del /s /q \\rdwlhsdevserver\root\*` to delete files from parent folder and all sub-folders. But I want to delete all folders and files except `\\rdwlhsdevserver\root\<folder>\`.

After running `cmd` output should be like:

> ```
> \\rdwlhsdevserver\root\user1\
> \\rdwlhsdevserver\root\abhay\
> \\rdwlhsdevserver\root\testuser\
> \\rdwlhsdevserver\root\devadmin\
> \\rdwlhsdevserver\root\admin\
> ```

Comment: What have you tried? And what is `rm`? There is no such command in `cmd`! What about files located in `\\rdwlhsdevserver\root\<folder>\`? Do they need to be deleted as well?

Comment: @aschipfl : sorry.. added unix commands. I have modified that part. I am able to delete all files from folders using "del /s /q d:\root\*" but folders will not be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over all sub-directories of `\\rdwlhsdevserver\root\` using a `for /D` loop, then loop over each sub-directory's sub-directories again by another `for /D` loop, then apply the `rmdir` (or `rd`) command on each of the returned items, like this:

```
for /D %%J in ("\\rdwlhsdevserver\root\*") do (
    for /D %%I in ("%%~J\*") do (
        rmdir /S /Q "%%~I"
    )
)
```

Or in command prompt directly:

```
for /D %J in ("\\rdwlhsdevserver\root\*") do @for /D %I in ("%~J\*") do @rmdir /S /Q "%~I"
```

---

For the sake of overall performance, if you want to delete directories *and* files, I recommend to do the above directory removal *before* the file deletion (`del /S /Q "\\rdwlhsdevserver\root\*"`). Note that your `del` command line also deletes files located in the directory `\\rdwlhsdevserver\root\`.

Answer (score 2):

```dos
pushd "\\rdwlhsdevserver\root" && (
    for /d %%a in (*) do ( cd "%%a" && ( 2>nul rmdir . /s /q & cd .. ) )
    del /f /q *
    popd
)
```

This will change the current active directory (`pushd`) to the target directory and if there are no problems (conditional execution operator `&&`) for each folder (`for /d`) change to it (`cd`), remove its contents (`rmdir`) and return to the parent folder. Once done, remove (`del`) the files inside the root folder and restore the initial active directory.

Why not change the inner `for` to `for /d %%a in (*) do rmdir "%%a" /s /q` ? Because this will also remove the folder. But if we first make the folder the current active directory (`cd`) we will be able to delete its contents but not the folder itself as it is in use (the `2>nul` is a redirection of the `stderr` stream to `nul` to hide the error in the `rmdir` saying it can not remove the folder because it is in use)